# IdHttp - Authentication Kerberos

Tags: indy

I use regularly IdHTTP (version 10) in my Delphi project, including with OpenSSL. 
It is possible with IdHTTP to negotiate an authentication Kerberos ?
If not, is there an alternative solution ?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Indy does not have any built-in support for Kerberos at this time (it does for NTLM, though).

However, `TIdHTTP` uses a plugin system for handling authentication at the HTTP layer.  You can write your own custom `TIdAuthentication`-derived class to handle Kerberos as needed, and then use the `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event to use your class whenever the server requests Kerberos authentication.